# If exist update else insert records in SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one staging table and want to insert data to `Main` table, so i want to check while inserting data from staging to Main table, if exists then update the records else insert as new records. Here the issue is both the staging as well as Main table does not have any key column based on which i can compare values.

Is it possible to do without having key columns i.e. primary key on both the tables? if yes, please, suggest me how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that there isn't a primary key created on those tables, or that there is no "logical" primary key on wich to identified every row?

Comment: I would recommend having unique identifiers on all your tables just for this kind of situation. You cannot check safely and precisely without them.

Comment: How will you know if you should update or insert if you don't have any columns that you can use to compare with?

Comment: *If it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table.*

Comment: @marc_s By what definition? While it doesn't sound like a good design in the question, it's still a table.

Comment: Think about this logically - How would you even specify an UPDATE to a record if you don't have a way to identify the record to be updated? You must have some way to know what is to be updated.

Comment: @Anders UP   It's a database table in the "physical" sense, that it's an object called a table in a DBMS. But in a "logical" sense, it is not a relational table. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_%28database%29 - "Each row is identified by the values appearing in a particular column subset which has been identified as a candidate key."

Comment: @AndersUP: a table without a primary key is just a (steaming) pile of data - not what I call a **real** table. That *might* be OK for a temporary / intermediate / staging table, e.g. for loading data - but anything you store permanently just needs a primary key...

Comment: @NWest I disagree. A key only ensures uniqueness or provides identity - and it does seem to be what the OP wants. However, I have yet to see a valid DBMS spec stating this as a requirement for a table. In MSSQL, take a look at the Master DB's systemtables. Ie. dbo.spt_values - many rows, no keys.

Comment: @AndersUP - But even in your example, dbo.spt_values does have a way to specify uniqueness - the combination of the "number" and "type" columns. http://en.sybinfo.org/s0000980.php

Again, I am not disagreeing that there are things in a physical DBMS called "tables". They just don't map 1-1 with the idea of a relational table, in which you expect to have a way to identify uniqueness. Even in many DBMS's, under the covers each row has a unique value (such as oracles ROWID, or SQL server's %%physloc%%).

Comment: @NWest Yes, the data in spt_values does have that kind of uniqueness, but it doesn't have a primary key per se - you don't need a key in order to achieve uniqueness. The OP doesn't say that he can't identify his data, indeed, his question would be moot if this was the case since his request would be impossible to achieve. (As you say, he must have some way to know what to update). His question is valid: Is it possible to achieve this without having a primary key on both tables? And I think that Aaron gives the correct answer by saying that if no set of data can define uniqueness, then no.

Answer (score 4):

If there is no unique key or set of data within a row to define uniqueness, then no.

The set of data can be a combination of the data in each column, creating a sum of parts which will provide uniqueness; however without exposure to your data you would need to make that decision.

Answer (score 0):

You write the WHERE-clause to include all the fields that make your record unique (ie. the fields that decide whether the record is new or should be updated.)

Take a look at this article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert.aspx) for hints on how to construct it.

If you are using SQL Server 2008r2, you could also use the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement - I haven't tried it on tables without keys, so I don't know whether it would work for you.